# Generate dll of each controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to give publish by generating separate `.dll` for each controller. Now it's creating just one single `.dll` for the whole project.

I have a solution - to create separate projects for each controller - but that has a lot of problems in maintaining the projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have only two options:

(1) create separate solutions, one per controller.

(2) create separate asp.net mvc projects within the same solution, again, one per controller.

Reference : https://forums.asp.net/t/1437620.aspx?MVC+How+to+compile+an+MVC+project+so+that+I+get+different+DLLs+for+each+controller+

Comment: but for large project its not possible and also difficult to redirect one page to another page. we can not get one projects session value to another...

Comment: You need to use sessionState SQLServer to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you  sir for your valuable suggestion, I will try this.